# Material Spinner vertical alignment

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm using angular material spinner in a mat table column. The spinner can be seen on the top side. I want to vertically align the spinner on the same level as other icons

What I'm currently getting is:

[image]

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th at-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div class="spinner-wrapper">
            <mat-spinner [diameter]="30" mode="indeterminate">
            </mat-spinner>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="neo-icon neo-icon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="neo-icon neo-icon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>

.spinner-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.mat-spinner {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

How can I align the spinner to the same level as other icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use another wrapper, and set the display to flex and use `align-items: center`:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="30" mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>

    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="neo-icon neo-icon-edit"></span>
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="neo-icon neo-icon-trash"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</td>
```

css:

```
.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[html/css pen](https://codepen.io/pierreduc/pen/XWWeVKx)